# Disable 'assign to' at workflow notifications

Tags: liferay, workflow, liferay-6

I'm working with Liferay Workflow and I've got a problem. The workflow goes this way: the user submits an asset and when the reviewer approves it, a notification is sent to the author. If the user opens the notification, there will be an option to assign the next workflow task to himself. But the user has not the responsible role to do this. It happens only at notifications, if the user goes to My account > My workflow tasks, there will be nothing assigned to him or his roles.
Any ideas how to solve it? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

this is some code from a working workflow where the "asset creator" does not need to assign the task to himself. I think you need to put  in the assignment, "user" reflects to the asset creator.

```
<task>
    <name>update</name>
    <metadata><![CDATA[{"xy":[160,208],"transitions":{"resubmit":{"bendpoints":[[178,171]]},"Submit changes":{"xy":[-18,2],"bendpoints":[[178,171]]}}}]]></metadata>
    <actions>
        <notification>
            <name>update notification</name>
            <template>${taskComments}</template>
            <template-language>freemarker</template-language>
            <notification-type>user-notification</notification-type>
            <recipients>
                <user/>
            </recipients>
            <execution-type>onEntry</execution-type>
        </notification>
        <notification>
            <name>update email notification</name>
            <description>Update required</description>
            <template>Dear ${userName}&lt;br&gt;</template>
            <template-language>freemarker</template-language>
            <notification-type>email</notification-type>
            <recipients>
                <user/>
            </recipients>
            <execution-type>onEntry</execution-type>
        </notification>
    </actions>
    <assignments>
        <user></user>
    </assignments>
    <task-timers>
      <task-timer>
        <name>default-assignment</name>
        <delay>
          <duration>1</duration>
          <scale>minute</scale>
        </delay>
        <blocking>true</blocking>
        <timer-actions>
          <timer-notification>
            <name>reminder update</name>
            <description>Reminder: update needed</description>
            <template>Dear ${userName}&lt;br&gt;</template>
            <template-language>freemarker</template-language>
            <notification-type>email</notification-type>
          </timer-notification>
          <reassignments>
            <user></user>
          </reassignments>
        </timer-actions>
      </task-timer>
    </task-timers>
    <transitions>
        <transition>
            <name>submit changes</name>
            <target>review</target>
        </transition>
    </transitions>
</task>
```

Comment: Hi, Michael! Thanks for your answer, but I think I didn't explain it good enough. This is the scenario:
User posts a submission on site, the reviewer #1 approves it. User will receive an email about it and a notification on the site. Something like "Hey, your post is going to level 2". Reviewer #2 will get a notification as well, 'cause there is a new review to do. But when the user _opens the notification_, it shows a page with the workflow task and a link letting him assign the task to himself, but he's not supposed to do that. It happens only when the user opens the notification.

Comment: so "reviewer #2" is not the initial author and you want to directly assign that task to "reviewer #2"?

Comment: I guess the problem is with the notification mail that user receives with the link to assign the task(which he is not supposed to get).@MaíraAraújo Could you plz post the whole/snippet for the workflow definition used for this scenario.